# What is Zongshen ZS125ST Carburetor 24mm KF Standard of Japan compatible with?

Tags: honda, motorcycle, part-identification, suzuki, parts

I have a carburetor "KF Standard of Japan" apparently  Zongshen ZS125ST Carburetor 24mm KF Standard of Japan.  What other makes/models is it compatible with?

Comment: I'm not seeing that it's compatible but with its self. But that is only through a cursory internet search.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the Japanese websites that might have this information are not searchable in English.